# Twitter API search not returning full text of tweet

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

> Right now my code is only returning some of the tweets

```
api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_key, access_secret)
r = api.request('tweets/search/fullarchive/:prod', {'query' : 'search term',"maxResults": "100",
"fromDate":"201901010000","toDate":"202001310000"})

csvFile = open('output.csv', 'a+')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in r:
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet['created_at'], tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'].encode('utf-8') if 'text' in tweet else tweet])

csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tweet is an extended tweet use `tweet['extended_tweet']['full_text']`.

Not all tweets are extended. So, use a test like this:

```
if 'extended_tweet' in tweet: 
    print(tweet['extended_tweet']['full_text'])
else if 'text' in tweet:
    print(tweet['text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
    tweets = api.search_tweets(q=search_term, tweet_mode='extended', count=tweet_amount)

for tweet in tweets:
    # check if the tweet is a retweet
    if tweet.full_text.startswith('RT @'):
        # if the tweet is a retweet, use the retweeted_status attribute
        full_text = tweet.retweeted_status.full_text
    else:
        full_text = tweet.full_text
```